# permissions to hive tables based on user roles

Tags: hive

how can we specify permissions for a table in hive in a way that only specific columns are visible to the users when they query according to there roles( I can use "views" but if they are 150 different roles)

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I have a External table in hive with 50 columns and millions of rows, Multiple teams query on the same table, If i have two teams A and B then I should specify permissions for the table in such a way that A should only see first 1-20 columns and B should see only 20-50 columns , when they query "Select * "on that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sentry to give role based privileges. You can create different groups and give access based on the group.

Refer this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cm_sg_sentry_service.html)